# Python discord.py command for admins and bot owner only

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm making a discord bot, and I want to make a command that only the bot owner and admins can use. here is my code:

```
class usefull(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command(name='(command)')        
    async def banWord(self, ctx, *, text):  
        if commands.is_owner or commands.has_role([786014220721979445, 786014064533831690, 933127964248375337, "Administrator", "Developers"]) or commands.has_permissions(administrator=True):
```

The if statement lets everyone through... I've tested almost everything.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you take a look over the [discord.py API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/) once more, specifically the entries for the methods you're trying to use.

More specifically, [`commands.is_owner()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.is_owner) is a *function*. You must *invoke* it. What you're returning here is the function itself in memory, which is truthy, and thus returns `True` in your condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
from discord.ext.commands import check
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions


def owner_admin():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        if not ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            if ctx.message.author.id != your_id_here:
                raise MissingPermissions(missing_permissions=['administrator'])
            elif ctx.message.author.id == your_id_here:
                return True
        else:
            return True
    return check(predicate)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can just do

```
@commands.command(name='(command)')  
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
```